# Proving that an expression is positive.

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to show that this function $F(a,p,\tau)$ is positive . I have tried numerically, and it seems to be the case, however I have a hard time really proving that it is positive.

I have:

$$0<a<1$$ $$0<p<1$$ $$\tau>0$$
$$b\doteq\frac{p\tau}{a(1-p)+\tau}$$
$$F(a,p,\tau)=p(1-p)+(p-b)^2-\frac{a(1-b)^2}{a+2\tau b^{-1}}.$$

Is there an easy way to show that the last expression is positive? I can try to substitute for $b$, then I get:

$$F(a,p,\tau)=p(1-p)+(p-\frac{p\tau}{a(1-p)+\tau})^2-\frac{a(1-\frac{p\tau}{a(1-p)+\tau})^2}{a+2\tau \frac{a(1-p)+\tau}{p\tau}}$$

I've tried simplifying it more, but I can stuck. Can  you see a way to show that this expression is positive?

Comment: The last expression is positive, however, it seems to be tedious to verify that it is smaller than the first two terms

Comment: When I simplify, I get $\displaystyle F(a,p,\tau) = \frac{(1-p) p (a+2 \tau)}{a (2-p)+2 \tau}$, which is certainly positive.

Comment: You can simplify by defining $t:=\frac{\tau}{a}$. You get $$F(t,p)=p(1-p)+\left(p-\frac{pt}{1-p+t}\right)^2-\frac{\left(1-\frac{pt}{1-p+t}\right)^2}{1+2t\frac{1-p+t}{pt}}$$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you, I was able to show that aswell knowing what the end result was. This was really good help because also getting the result now just knowing it is positive, is very useful.